# Space between columns html

Tags: html

This is the code that I was given but it still has some problems that I can't fix. What I want to do is to add space between each column. What I can do atm is to add another box and it gets filled out, tho I only need and want 3.
[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDt4s.png)
and this below is the code? Any quick fix for this?

Thanks!

```
<div class="page-width">
{% if section.settings.title != blank %}
<div class="section-header text-center">
<h2>{{ section.settings.title | escape }}</h2>
</div>
{% endif %}

<div class="grid {% unless section.blocks.size == 5 %}grid--uniform{% endunless %} grid--flush-bottom">
{%- assign grid_item_width = 'medium-up--one-quarter' -%}
{%- assign max_height = 345 -%}
{% case section.blocks.size %}

{% when 1 %}
{%- assign grid_item_width = 'medium-up--one-half' -%}
{%- assign max_height = 530 -%}
{% when 2 %}
{%- assign grid_item_width = 'medium-up--one-half' -%}
{%- assign max_height = 530 -%}
{% when 4 %}
{%- assign grid_item_width = 'medium-up--one-quarter' -%}
{%- assign max_height = 530 -%}
{% endcase %}
{% for block in section.blocks %}
{% if section.blocks.size == 5 and forloop.index < 3 %}
{%- assign column_width = 'medium-up--one-half' -%}
{%- assign max_height = 530 -%}
{% else %}
{%- assign column_width = grid_item_width -%}
{% endif %}
{% if section.blocks.size == 5 and forloop.index == 3 %}<div class="clearfix"></div>{% endif %}

<div class="grid__item {{ column_width }} {{ section.settings.align_text }} small--one-half" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
{% if block.settings.enable_image %}
{% if block.settings.image != blank %}

{% if block.settings.button_label == blank and block.settings.button_link != blank %}
<a href="{{ block.settings.button_link }}">
<p>
{{ block.settings.image | img_url: image_size | img_tag }}
</p>
</a>
{% else%}
<p><a href="{{ block.settings.button_link }}">
{{ block.settings.image | img_url: image_size | img_tag }}
</a>
</p>
{% endif %}
{% else %}
<p>
{{ 'image' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
</p>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% if block.settings.title != blank %}
<h4 class="uppercase home--uppercase">{{ block.settings.title | escape }}</h4>
{% endif %}
{% if block.settings.text != blank %}
<div class="rte">{{ block.settings.text }}</div>
{% endif %}
{% if block.settings.button_label != blank and block.settings.button_link != blank %}
<a href="{{ block.settings.button_link }}" class="btn btn--clear btn--square uppercase">
{{ block.settings.button_label | escape }}
</a>
{% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>

{% if section.blocks.size == 0 %}
{% include 'no-blocks' %}
{% endif %}
</div>
</div>

{% schema %}
{
"name": "Text columns with images",
"class": "index-section",
"settings": [
{
"type": "text",
"id": "title",
"label": "Heading",
"default": "Text columns with images"
},
{
"type": "select",
"id": "homepage_columns_color",
"label": "Background color",
"default": "homepage--white",
"options": [
{ "value": "homepage--white", "label": "White"},
{ "value": "homepage--light", "label": "Light"},
{ "value": "homepage--splash", "label": "Accent"},
{ "value": "homepage--dark", "label": "Dark"}
]
},
{
"type": "select",
"id": "align_text",
"label": "Text alignment",
"default": "text-center",
"options": [
{
"value": "text-left",
"label": "Left"
},
{
"value": "text-center",
"label": "Centered"
}
]
}
],
"blocks": [
{
"type": "text_block",
"name": "Column",
"settings": [
{
"type": "checkbox",
"id": "enable_image",
"label": "Show image",
"default": true
},
{
"type": "image_picker",
"id": "image",
"label": "Image"
},
{
"type": "text",
"id": "title",
"label": "Heading",
"default": "Add a title or tagline"
},
{
"type": "richtext",
"id": "text",
"label": "Text",
"default": "<p>Share blog posts, products, or promotions with your customers. Use this text to describe products, share details on availability and style, or as a space to display recent reviews or FAQs.</p>"
},
{
"type": "text",
"id": "button_label",
"label": "Button label",
"info": "Leave blank to link from image"
},
{
"type": "url",
"id": "button_link",
"label": "Button link"
}
]
}
],
"presets": [
{
"name": "Text columns custom",
"category": "Text",
"blocks": [
{
"type": "text_block"
},
{
"type": "text_block"
},
{
"type": "text_block"
}
]
}
]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: Have you tried `&nbsp;` in your code?

Comment: Try adding `padding: 0 8px` to `grid__item`.

Comment: Sorry, I have a hard time finding where to enter the codes :/

Comment: Well you can use a separate css file